# Splicing objects from an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to remove an object from an array if a particular value for a key matches a given string:

Example data:

```
array = [{_id: "abc", test: "123"}, 
         {_id: "def", test: "123"},
         {_id: "ghi", test: "123"}];
```

Here is my loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var x = "123"
    if (array[i].test == x) {
       array.splice(i, 1)
    }
}
```

This should return an empty array but it's leaving one object in the array (the last one) and I've got no clue why.

Comment: I realise the problem now - third time around the loop, array.length = 1 and i = 2. What's the best solution?

Comment: Iterating backwards is one way to work around the problem. Change your loop header to: `for ( var i = array.length; i--; )`. That works because when you remove an element only the indices of elements past that one are affected; elements before it are not touched, so if you are iterating backwards, removing an element won't affect the index of future elements in your loop.

Answer (score 4):

You must not increment `i` if you remove an element.

Suppose the array has two matching elements.

The first iteration, i = 0

```
i ==>>  element 1
        element 2
```

You then remove element 1, and increment i

```
        element 2
i ==>>
```

There are many ways you can correct this. Here's an example that replaces your `for` loop with a `while` loop.

```
var i = 0;
while (i < array.length) {
    var x = "123"
    if (array[i].test == x) {
       array.splice(i, 1)
    } else {
       ++i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
array = [
  {id: "abc", test: "123"}, 
  {id: "def", test: "456"},
  {id: "ghi", test: "789"}
];
let x = "123";
let i = array.findIndex(data => data.test === x);
    if (i !== -1) {
        array.splice(i, 1);
    } else ...
console.log(array);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Hello! Yes, I tried to explain it haha ​​the problem is that it is the first time that I leave a comment here and don't believe it, it was difficult for me because I tried to write and it said error. I don't understand! Sorry, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
array = array.filter(function(array) {
  var x = "123";
  return array.test !== x;
})
```

Comment: But that's not using *splice*, which seems to be the point of the exercise.

Comment: @RobG Cleaner and easier to use imho. I'm always open to new methods to solve a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a function that takes the index and event values from the html and processes in ts

app.component.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let container of containers; let i = index;" 
      [(ngModel)]="miningname"
            ngDefaultControl>
              <td>
    <input *ngIf="addMore" type="text" class = "form-control" 
     placeholder="Key" 
     [(ngModel)]="container.key2Name" 
       (ngModelChange)="textKeyChangedMore($event,i)">
</td></tr>
```

app.component.ts

```
  textKeyChangedMore(eventMore, indexMore) {


    var valueLength = this.selectedAPIName.length

      var i = indexMore+1;
      if (this.selectedAPIName[i].value == undefined ) {

        this.selectedAPIName.splice(indexMore + 1, 1, { key: eventMore, value: undefined });
      }
      else if (this.selectedAPIName[i].value !== undefined) {

        this.selectedAPIName.splice(indexMore + 1, 1, { key: eventMore, value: this.selectedAPIName[i].value });
      }
}
```